# Can't use awgn on Octave Windows

Tags: windows, package, octave

I know `awgn` is in the `communications` package. But I installed it from [OctaveForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/octave/files/Octave_Windows%20-%20MinGW/) and I still get a `error: help: 'awgn' not found` when I type `help awgn`

Comment: Is the communications package loaded? Try `pkg list` and check if the package is listed and if there is a `*` next to the communication package. If that is the case, then `awgn` should be found by octave.

Comment: @Woltan The package is there but without the `*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Woltan indicated the package was installed but not loaded. The problem was solved with

```
 pkg load communications
```